# Getting a 401 for "The access token provided in the Authorization header is invalid"

Tags: amadeus

not sure what I'm missing, I'm getting a 401 for invalid token in the auth header, curl command below (dummy API key). Any help is appreciated, thanks!

`curl -H 'Authorization: xxx12345678865556' 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers/?origin=PAR&destination=JFK&departureDate=2018-09-25&returnDate=2018-09-28&adults=1&travelClass=BUSINESS&nonStop=true&max=2'`

I've tried 'accessToken' and included 'Bearer' as well, still getting the 401.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amadeus API Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080663/amadeus-api-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

This is the curl with the right header, replace the *access_token* by your token.

curl -X GET \
  "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/reference-data/urls/checkin-links?airline=1X" \
      -H "Authorization: Bearer *access_token*"

You will find a guide to help you [here](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/developer-guides/blob/master/guides/authorization.md).

Note that the token is valid for 30min.